How to literally translate this: 但汉字叔叔每天的日程却安排得很满
中国，60多岁已经是退休的年纪了。但汉字叔叔每天的日程却安排得很满。
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 21. How to literally translate this: 但汉字叔叔每天的日程却安排得很满?
I have reached that point:
但(but)汉字叔叔(Chinese characters' uncle)每天(every day)的日程(schedule)却(however)安排(schedule)得很满(very full)。
As you can see it doesn't make sense. Especially the two schedules: 日程, 安排？

但(but)汉字叔叔(uncle 汉字) 每天的(every day's)日程(schedule)却(="反而/然而” - at the same time)安排得(arranged)很满(quite full).
Now you shall be able to make a sentence according to English grammar. Good luck.

"scheduled a schedule" might sound weird but it is not wrong, you can always use synonyms to avoid using the same word for the verb and the noun in the same phrase
日程(schedule)(n)
安排(arrange)(v)
日程安排得很满 = schedule is arranged very full
